# control LED with Arduino through webpage

Tags: arduino, processing

want to control an LED through website, I used Processing program and every thing work just fine. but when I unplugged my arduino from the laptop, the arduino can not response to the request from the web. It works otherwise. I don't want to connect my arduino all the time to my lap top.

I have a file called LEDstate.txt which sends data include 0 or 1 to the Processing program, and I have simple html page with ON OFF hyperlinks include the state of the txt file.

these are the codes I have used

The code for the Processing program

```
import processing.serial.*;
 Serial port;

 void setup()  {
 /*  change the number between the brackets after Serial.list() to meet the PORT number that arduino is connected to */

    port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 9600); 
}
 void draw() {

  String LED_Status[] = loadStrings("http://www.daffostore.com/ard/LEDstate.txt"); 
  print(LED_Status[0]);  

  if (LED_Status[0].equals("1") == true) {
    println("LEDstate.txt have ( 1 )- sending 'H' to Arduino ");
    port.write('H'); 
 } 

 else {
    println("LEDstate.txt have ( 0 )- sending 'L' to Arduino ");
    port.write('L');  
 }

  delay(1000); // This makes a 5 sec delay between each check for the value that is stored in LED.txt
 }
```

and this the arduino IDE code

```
int Led = 13;  // led is connected to pin number 12

int incomingByte; // variable to read the incoming serial data coming from "Processing" sketch through USB cable

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {  // checking if there is incoming serial data

    incomingByte = Serial.read();  // reading the incoming data from "Processing"

    if (incomingByte == 'H') { // if "Processing"" is sending H , turn on the LED 
      digitalWrite(Led, HIGH);   }

    if (incomingByte == 'L') {  // if "Processing" is sending L , turn off the LED 
      digitalWrite(Led, LOW);  }
  }
}
```

and this is the php code for the request

```
<?php
$onoroff = $_GET["state"]; // Declares the request from index.html as a variable
$textfile = "LEDstate.txt"; // Declares the name and location of the .txt file

$fileLocation = "$textfile";
$fh = fopen($fileLocation, 'w   ') or die("Something went wrong!"); // Opens up the .txt file for writing and replaces any previous content
$stringToWrite = "$onoroff"; // Write either 1 or 0 depending on request from index.html
fwrite($fh, $stringToWrite); // Writes it to the .txt file
fclose($fh); 

header("Location: index.html"); // Return to frontend (index.html)
?>
```

Comment: Uhm, as far as I can understand the arduino is NOT connected to the internet. If so, well, you can either hope that magicians exist and find a way to magically tell the board what to do, or find another way to do it. Personally I'm not really into magic, so I prefer the second option. Now, to let arduino download data from the internet you will need 1) a proper ethernet/wifi shield or 2) a PC to make the requests. Since you don't want to leave the laptop on you can use an embedded pc (like the raspberry PI, and then you won't need the arduino but you can just use the rPI GPIOs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a convoluted solution:

`[Browser (any PC)] -> {the web} -> [PHP web server (PC)] -> /LEDstate.txt (PC) -> [Processor (PC)] -> Serial Port (PC to Arduino) -> [Arduino IDE code (Arduino)] -> [LED]`

As you can see you have your PC doing a large chunk of the work. As such you can't just turn it off.

Ideally what you want is:

`[Browser (any PC)] -> {the web} -> [Web server (Board; e.g. Arduino)] -> [LED]`

To get here you would need to make the Arduino talk to the internet or switch boards and select one that can already talk to the internet.

You could use an [Arduino Wifi Shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield) or an [Arduino Eithernet Shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield) and [re-write the "Web server"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer) in the Arduino IDE (you will no longer require either the "processor" or current "Arduino IDE code").

You could change boards and select a board that has networking built in. For example you could go with the [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) which can run PHP and Apache and even has an [example on how to do just this](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2014/07/PHP-on-Raspberry-Pi).

Or you could use the [ESP8266](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266). This little guy can use the [Arduino IDE](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino) or can use [Lua](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html) or a bunch of different environments.

Which option you select will depend on how much you want to spend and how tied you are to using Arduino. The Wifi and eithernet shields are more expensive than the ESP8266, but the ESP8266 is not comparable with existing Arduino boards.